# лямбда выражение в сортировке

Tags: java, lambda

Стоит задача отсортировать все буквы в строке по алфавиту. Программа должна игнорировать регистр при сортировке.

Написал такой код :

```
char[] charstr = str.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(charstr, 
  (char a , char b) -> {Character.compare(Character.toLowerCase(a) , Character.toLowerCase(b))});
str = new String(charstr);
```

получаю сообщение, что не хватает `;`, но синтаксис вроде правильный. Кто может подсказать в чем ошибка?

Comment: ну если компилятор говорит что не хватает ; - значит все-таки неправильный синтаксис. после вызова compare() (4 строка) надо ;

Comment: Вы забыли точку с запятой аккурат перез закрывающейся фигурной скобкой. Должно быть так: `.toLowerCase(b));})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге так решил :

```
String[] split = str.split("");

Arrays.sort(split , String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
str = new String("");
for (int i = 0 ; i < split.length; i++)
    str += split[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Варианты:

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Comparator;

    public class SortHelp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str = "bZDFghA";
            String[] sAr = str.split("");
            Arrays.sort(sAr, (o1, o2) -> o1.toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.toLowerCase()));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sAr));
        }
    }
```

и

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Comparator;

    public class SortHelp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String str = "bZDFghA";
            String[] sAr = str.split("");
            Arrays.sort(sAr, Comparator.comparing(String::toLowerCase));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sAr));
        }
    }
```